# "Error: Unexpected close tag" Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

When running the command `cordova platform add android`, I get a bunch of errors popping up in the terminal.

```
Caelans-MBP:HiltonExtraordinaryFB Caelan$ cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.phonegap.hiltonsimplyfb
    Name: Hilton F&B
    Android target: android-19
Copying template files...
Project successfully created.
Error: Unexpected close tag
Line: 8
Column: 12
Char: >
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:347:8)
    at strictFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:364:22)
    at closeTag (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:523:7)
    at Object.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:948:29)
    at XMLParser.feed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
    at ElementTree.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:263:10)
    at Object.exports.XML (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:593:13)
    at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/util/xml-helpers.js:126:38)
    at android_parser.update_from_config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/android_parser.js:221:23)
    at android_parser.update_project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/android_parser.js:349:14)
Caelans-MBP:HiltonExtraordinaryFB Caelan$
```

Is there any way I can resolve these errors so I can continue.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your `config.xml` file it's hard to troubleshoot, but I'll bet it's the name of your app:

Name: Hilton F&B

Since config.xml must be valid XML, make sure you're using the `&amp;` ampersand entity and not a raw ampersand, which has meaning in XML syntax.

Comment: I forgot to say I fixed it. I can't remember what it was. But the name of the app is in a CDATA tag, so it can't be the ampersand.  Can it?

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue and wanted to share my experience. The problem was ***Unexpected close tag***, in your config.xml file you forgot to close one or two tags, if you look at the line which is shown as error, there is not error even, but somewhre in your config.xml file there is tag not closed. Please, make sure all tags have closed correctly.

Comment: This was such a long time ago, but the given error message was misleading, as it wasn't actually a missing closing tag causing it. I can't remember exactly what it was, but I remember it being something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I **was missing one closing tag in the string** that I was parsing to XML. It had a starting tag not closing tag.
Make sure to check all the Tags have starting and closing tags.

If you have XML on runtime and cannot be checked manually, You can use an amazing npm package which provide `validate` method to check if XML is valid.

npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser

example:

```
const { XMLValidator } = require('fast-xml-parser');
const result = XMLValidator.validate(
  "<root>Run the , ...' >/etc/hosts.allow where each <net>/<mask> combination (for example, '192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0') represents one network block in use by your organization that requires access to this system</root>",
  {
    allowBooleanAttributes: true,
  }
);
```

Just sharing, might be helpful for someone.